# How spark load only part files within a directory?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a directory which has more than 10,000 files with the same schema.

Because loading and scanning all files is very time-consuming, I hope to load only part of these files arbitrarily.

For example, the file list is `1.csv, 2.csv,......,1000.csv`.

I wonder if there is a way to only load `1.csv, 10.csv, 97.csv,...`(the files are picked randomly) so that I can avoid scanning all files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of filenames to the csv reader.

e.g.

```py
# you'll need full paths here unless the files are in your working directory
filelist = ['1.csv', '10.csv', '97.csv']   
df = spark.read.csv(filelist)
```

in Scala it would be

```scala
val filelist = Seq("1.csv", "10.csv", "97.csv")
val df = spark.read.csv(filelist: _*)
```

Comment: Better if you point out how to gen such a file list...10K in sight!

Comment: @thebluephantom I think the OP wants to load an arbitrarily-picked list...? not all the files

Comment: Yes, the list is randomly picked so it can not be manually assigned. I can only assign the path of the directory.